# Discover Reports - time of back end data refresh

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, analytics

I've setup a daily master Discover report to show main email metrics for the previous day.

This runs at 7am EST.

For the past few days it hasn't updated with the previous day's data following its run.  It's currently 10.30am EST and it still hasn't updated.  However, this data is available when accessing it from Email > Tracking > Sends.

Am I running the report too early? Typically does the data not refresh on the backend for Discover reports by this time?  Or has anyone else noticed a delay in this data refresh recently?

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, Discover reports are not the best or most reliable source. The data is refreshed via an Automation in Automation Studio. Check this doc to be able to find it (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_di_restart_paused_account.htm&type=5) I believe searching for `E-I-L` should have it show up.

Comment: Thank you, I checked and that Automation had failed.  I wish this platform was more robust!